# java Binary search for multiple occurrences in arraylist using regex

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

Below you can see my code. It reads words with lenght 3 from sort.txt and saves them into arraylist. Then user is asked to input a word he is searching for. User can also input " * " matching any possible letters from a-z

For example:

```
My list: [AKP, ALU, ALU, AMD, AMZ, APP, APZ, ARD, AZS, AZS, Ada, Adi, Amy, Ana, Arh, Arh,]
```

User input: ALU

Program returns ALU found at 1

SO THIS PART WORKS, here is the problem.

List is the same.
User input: A**

So the program should return:

```
AKP found at 0

ALU found at 1

ALU found at 2

AMD found at 3
```

and so on

Basically all words starting with A.

Please if anyone could help me out would be awesome kinda stuck for the past 2h here.

```
public class proba{


private final static int NOT_FOUND = -1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String izbira;
    int dolzina=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_input;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();


    try {

        File file = new File("sort.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String vrstica;

        while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (vrstica.length() == 3) {
                list3.add(vrstica);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(list3);
        do{
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter lenght of word:");
                if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                    dolzina = in.nextInt();
                } else if (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.printf("Wrong entry!%n ",
                            in.nextLine());
                } 
            } while (dolzina <= 0);

        Collections.sort(list3);

        System.out.println("Enter a word for unknown character enter * :");
        user_input = input.nextLine();
        user_input = user_input.replace("*", ".");

        System.out.println("Sorted list: [length: " + list3.size() + "]");
        System.out.println(list3);


        if (dolzina == 3) {
            if(user_input.charAt(0) != '*') {
                int index = binarySearch(list3, user_input);
                System.out.println("Found" + user_input +" at " + index);
            }
            else 
            for (int i = 0; i < list3.size(); i++) {
                String s = (String) list3.get(i);
                if (s.matches(user_input))
                    System.out.println(s);
            }

        }

        dolzina=-1;
        System.out.println("Ponovni vnos (da/ne):");
        Scanner inn= new Scanner (System.in);
        izbira = inn.next();

    }while (izbira.equalsIgnoreCase("da"));
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}


public static int binarySearch(List<String> integerList, String searchValue) {

int low = 0;
int high = integerList.size() - 1;
int mid = (low + high) / 2;

while (low <= high && !integerList.get(mid).equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)) {

    if (integerList.get(mid).compareTo(searchValue) < 0) {
        low = mid + 1;
    } else {
        high = mid - 1;
    }

    mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (low > high) {
        mid = NOT_FOUND;
    }

}
return mid;

 }

 }
```

Comment: When you debug, do you see the control going to the line:  s.matches(user_input)) .... and failing? In other words, if you put an "else" to that if, does it show you that it is coming to the else for each entry in list3 ?

Comment: i know that else doesnt work at the moment but its not important

Comment: The way you have written your binarySearch() it tries to find an exact match. Is that right? Or did you mean it to do something else?  Also, you're checking for asterisk after you have replaced asterisk  with dot, but that does not impact the question.

Comment: yes becuse i dont know how to write it to find all matches with * that why i am asking. This is what i have how to fix it

Comment: The exact match is fine, because even if you were to change that method it returns only one index, but you want to see all the matches. So, let the code flow to the else part as you intended to do... but do this ANY TIME there is a wildcard in ANY position.

Comment: but i need to do binary search! This would be a crossword helper. So exact match would be stupid to input. I need: if we know first or first 2 letters of 1 word to use binary search and return all possible solution starting with those 2 letters. Otherewise if it stats with wildcard do ELSE loop